# how to get URL of a PDF document in my google drive to use as MediaUrl for a twilio fax

Tags: google-drive-api, twilio

How can I get the real URL of a PDF document on google drive that ends with FILE_NAME.pdf so I can use it as the `"MediaUrl"` parameter to send a Twilio fax

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, and I'm answering my own question.

You can use google download url for twilio fax `"MediaUrl"` parameter which you can get easily like this.

```
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var url = file.getDownloadUrl();
```

But make sure you set the sharing to public so Twilio can access it like this

```
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
```

I set the sharing when I created the file dont know if order makes a difference.

There might be a security comprimise if you're concerned with making you're file public.
There are ways to keep it private and authorize Twilio or with a signed Url but I'm not so familiar with that, yet.